# View clipping after CATransform3DRotate

Tags: ios, swift, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to apply perspective transformation to a view (let's call it `subview`) that only draws a square along its frame, is centered horizontally in its superview and is 3/4 of its superview's width: 
[image]

I'm using this snippet:

```
var rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = CGFloat(-1.0/280.0)
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 30.0 * CGFloat.pi / 180.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
subview.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform
```

Which does the transformation I need, but has a weird effect — the right part of the rectangle is "clipped":

[image]

What's causing it? How can I avoid it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it's a good-old bounds versus frame problem. The frame becomes wider after the transformation and doesn't fit into the bounds anymore.

As I still wanted it to be horizontally centered, this snipped did the trick:

```
let transformedFrame  = segmentView.layer.frame
let transformedBounds = segmentView.layer.bounds
let correctedBoundsX  = (transformedFrame.width - transformedBounds.width) / 2

segmentView.layer.bounds = CGRect(x: correctedBoundsX, y: transformedBounds.origin.y, width: transformedBounds.width, height: transformedBounds.height)
```